# How do I call a function and pass in an object with a variable as a property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run the following function: `doStuff(objName.variable, variable);`

The object `objName` has a property that the variable `variable` is equal too.

How would I make this work where instead of trying to find the property `variable` of `objName`, the code tries to find the property of `objName` that is stored in `variable`.

Thanks.

Comment: Include a sample of your object please.

Comment: Maybe some code would give context to your question, but as it stands, it is very hard to determine what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I personally have no clue what you are trying to do with that description. Maybe code sample with that you are trying to do would help.

Comment: Do you mean, `objName[variableContainingPropertyName]` ?

Comment: I could guess and assume this is what you're trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/38rnbzst/  but I think we need more of a context or sample code to really understand what you're looking for. Do you want to see if an object contains a variable, e.g. object has key named "test1", and the variable = "test1", or are you trying to see if a object's key e.g object.key = value - has a value of the variable "test1", etc.

Comment: @James Yeah, thanks.